# PL/SQL Developer doesn't find records with russian letters

Tags: oracle, encoding

In local machine I do this query:

```
    select * from allObjects where status = 'Изменено'
```

I get empty result.
In server I do same query and get all records. DB and schema are same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this happens because of client session NLS_LANG is different from server language. Check your session NLS_LANG:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;
```

Try to set environment variable on your client computer from command line before connection:

```
set nls_lang=AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251
```

Here are some links to read about that:

- [RUS: Oracle - Delphi -
  NLS_LANG](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=218373)
- [RUS: Параметры NLS уровня
  сеанса](http://all-oracle.ru/content/view/?part=2&id=112)
- [Determine Oracle session client character
  set?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7765/determine-oracle-session-client-character-set)
- [Oracle: NLS_LANG
  FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html#_Toc110410545)

Answer (score 3):

If you add 'N' before literal constant system will use Unicode:

select * from allObjects where status = N'Изменено'